# IntelliJ mark red but resolved after delete and add again

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I met this for several times. So here is the thing, I open my java project, and there is a function call marked red "cannot access ...". But we I delete the call and write the same thing again, it resolved. So what happened here? Any solution rather than delete and add it again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like just a bug. You may have to delete and add again whenever it happens, but that doesn't seem like too much of a hassle. The IntelliJ bug page can be found [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA).